# Pass JS function to C in wasm (No emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c, clang, webassembly

Alright, I am unable to find anything on this, as its almost all emscripten code,
I am trying to call a JS function in C

Example:

JS:

```js
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("./out.wasm")).then((assembly) => {
    c = assembly.instance.exports;
    c.passFunc(() => {
        console.log(`called`);
    });
});
```

C:

```c
void passFunc(void (*f)()) {
    f();
}
```

Expected output (Console):

`called`

Actual output:

Here is how I compile it:

```bash
~$ clang -O3 --target=wasm64 -emit-llvm -c -S index.c
~$ llc -march=wasm64 -filetype=obj index.ll
~$ wasm-ld --no-entry --export-all --lto-O3 -O3 -z stack-size=8192 -o out.wasm index.o
```

(Generates out.wasm, index.o, index.s, index.ll)

Comment: Based on my very limited amount of research just now, it looks like you can't directly do this since you can only pass numeric types to C functions. You'd have to do some bootstrapping and other workaround stuff. All of this stuff is handled by emscripten for you. Under the hood, emscripten uses clang/llvm, it just has nice libraries added.

Comment: @Kyle I am aware of emscripten, but I would rather use just wasm / c, as in emcc it should compile to wasm + js, meaning that it should be able to have just c with js functions, I will check their source code, I am asking on here due to there being almost 0 examples of non-emcc code, with me just converting js to c, I just need the few webgl functions for optimal gpu usage, not cpu (Sorry for the bad English, I am German and I have been learning English for ~6 years do to my programming carrier)